# preg_match - where do I err?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Friends,
I'm rushing towards deadline and I think that makes me do childish mistakes.
Here I have validation that requires regex and each time I input valid expression preg_match returns false. It is long now I'm trying to spot error but I cannot! I have googled and AFAICS, things seems alright please help me spot the error.
Thanks,
Stefano

```
<?php

$string = "37961/T.08";//valid ID, it is supposed to match
$regex = '/^[0-9]{5,}/[a-zA-Z]\.[0-9]{2,}/';
if (preg_match($regex, $string)) {
    echo 'matched expression!';
}  else {
    echo 'unmatched expression pattern';//comes here instead of valid regex!
}

?>
```

Comment: Make error_reporting() a bit more sensitive then it will tell you that the regex is wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you need to escape your `/`

```
$regex = '/^[0-9]{5,}\/[a-zA-Z]\.[0-9]{2,}/';
```

Comment: Yeah! It works. Why does it need to be escaped? I didn't see it in special regex characters. I though only \ is to be escaped?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @stefano - because the / is the regex delimiter. It sees that as the end of the pattern.